# how to set table width using php value

Tags: php, width

I have function to app up some values and I want to make a single bar graph with a table.The value shows up properly but table value does not work What am I doing wrong?

```
<table width="<?php     
     add($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$y,$z); ?>" 
     border="1"> <tr><td><?php 
     add($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$y,$z);?>%</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: `add()` sums up all values? Maybe you are missing an `echo`?

Comment: We need to know what add() does in order to be able to help

Comment: just use array to avoid that mess

Answer (score 0):

Pass the return of the function to a variable and write it with echo on the desired places. It will be much faster than calling it 2 times and easy to understand.

```
<?php
    $value = add($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k,$l,$m,$n,$o,$p,$q,$r,$s,$t,$u,$v,$y,$z);
?>

<table width="<?php echo $value; ?>" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?>%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```